# Unable to traverse array fully in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I had this question to solve:

Find the length of increasing subarrays in the given array and print length of each segment in a new line

Here's what I have done so far:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(){
     int c = 0;
     int a[] = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7};
     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[i-1]) {
            c++;
        }
        else {
            printf("%d\n", c);
            c=1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My expected answer is:

```
2

4
```

but I am getting only `2`, on increasing `i` to `7`, I am getting correct answer, am I doing something wrong in traversing the array because the length is `6` and `i<6` should have given the correct answer

Apologies in advance if the question is too trivial, just getting started.

Comment: `a[i-1]` is out-of-range when `i=0`.

Comment: Hello. The first time you do your for loop, i equal 0 but you acces "i - 1" index, so the "-1" index. I don't think it's what you want.

Comment: Your condition that prints the length of the current increasing sequence is never triggered for the final run. You have to code it some other way (eg: adding an extra print after the end of the loop).

Comment: @PaulHankin It actually works if I change the value from i<6 to i<7 in the for loop

Comment: If you increase the loop condition to `i<7` then my original comment becomes correct as you will access off the end of the array (which is undefined behavior and may or may not work).

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Because you have included in this line:

```
if (a[i] > a[i-1])
```

`i` starts with a 0 but `a[-1]` doesn't exist.
To fix your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int c = 0;
    int a[] = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7};
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[i-1]) 
            c++;
        else {
            printf("%d\n", c);
            c=1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this code print `4` for the final sequence?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it with a single `printf` in the loop if you loop over all values from 0 to the array length, and treat the first and last iterations as special cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int c = 0;
    int a[] = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7};
    const int len = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        if (i < len && (i == 0 || a[i] > a[i-1])) {
            c++;
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", c);
            c = 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `i < len` makes sure that the code does not access `a[len]`, which is out of bounds. When `i` equals `len` the code reaches the `else` part to print the length of the final segment.

The `i == 0` makes sure that the code does not access `a[-1]`, which is out of bounds, but we want it to increment `c` for the first entry in the array.

---

The code can be simplified a bit by initializing `c = 1` and starting the loop at `i = 1`.  By doing that, the first element of the array has already been accounted for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int c = 1;
    int a[] = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7};
    const int len = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        if (i < len && a[i] > a[i-1]) {
            c++;
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", c);
            c = 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

The code will run slightly faster if the code inside the loop is simplified as much as possible, eliminating the `i < len` test inside the loop, and terminating the loop when `i` reaches `len` (i.e. continue the loop if `i < len`), but that will require the length of the final segment to be printed separately after the `for` loop has terminated:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int c = 1;
    int a[] = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7};
    const int len = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[i-1]) {
            c++;
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", c);
            c = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

If there is a requirement for the code to work when the overall sequence has zero length, then the final `printf` would print the wrong value `1`. That could be dealt with either by setting `c` to 0 when `len` is 0, or by skipping the final `printf` if `len` is 0. (It depends whether you want to print anything at all when the overall sequence has zero length.)

Comment: Do you need `if (c > 1)` before the final `printf()`?  If the last two entries in the array are 13 and 3, then `c == 1` but a sequence of 1 isn't exactly interesting.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think the sum of the printed segment lengths ought to match the length of the array. E.g., for a monotonically decreasing sequence, it should print `1` `len` times.

Comment: The expected output quoted in the question doesn't require `1` to be printed for the consecutive numbers `3` and `2`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That sequence (I mean the complete sequence) isn't monotonically decreasing. (The `3` is part of the first segment.)

Comment: Oh, that's curious!  What would make it monotonically decreasing?  Why is the previous sequence 1, 3 monotonically increasing when 3, 2 is not monotonically decreasing?  (I see you edited your comment — I'm unconvinced by the addendum about 3 being part of the first sequence…. However, we may have to agree to disagree in the absence of information from the OP, which is unlikely to be available.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Edits clashed - I meant the complete sequence, not the subsequence.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well I'm curious what you would expect the output should be for an array `{1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6}`? I would expect `3` `1` `2`, but it seems that _you_ wouldn't consider the `1` to be meaningful!

Comment: If I understand your thoughts correctly, if the input array contained …, 23, 25, 27, 26, 24, 22, … then you'd argue that the sequence …, 23, 25, 27 was the end of an increasing sequence, and 26, 24, 22, … was the beginning of a decreasing sequence.  Or, in other words, a given entry in the array can only be part of an increasing sequence or a decreasing sequence but not the end of one _and_ the start of another.  It's a tenable position; it isn't the way I've usually seen it described.  Hence my concern.  But, as stated previously, we will probably have to agree to disagree.

Comment: For `{1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6}`, I'd expect an output of 3 (for the increasing sequence `1, 3, 5`) and 2 (for the increasing sequence `2, 6`) — given that the question only seems to be interested in the lengths of increasing sequences.  If both increasing and decreasing sequences were to be counted, then I'd expect 3 (for `1, 3, 5`), 3 for the decreasing sequence `5, 4, 2`, and 2 (for `2, 6`).  The sum of the lengths does not necessarily equal the count of the elements in the array — for either 'only increasing sequences' or 'both increasing and decreasing sequences'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It depends if you want the output to give some indication of the position of each increasing subsequence, which including the `1`s does (by accumulating the reported lengths).

Comment: If you wanted to determine the positions of the sequences, then you'd need to include the lengths of the decreasing sequences too.  But given `{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}` (liftoff!), I'd not expect to see eleven `1`'s printed.  There isn't enough information in the question to deal with such esoteric design issues, which is not very surprising.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I guess I'm reading the problem as "partition the sequence into segments of maximal length such that elements of each segment are in strictly increasing order, and print the length of each segment".